# Imputation of a (weird) multivariate outcome

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I am working with a dataset in which the outcome of interest is a vector of dates of particular events: (date_1,date_2,date_3,...,date_n). Some of these outcome vectors are completely missing, but I always know the number of events. I need to impute these outcomes and I can assume that the distribution of dates is independent of missing status conditional on the number of events.

I don't really know how to impute these data. I don't think I can easily fit a predictive model of the outcome since the dates are correlated so I would need a complicate multivariate distribution for the outcome.

I have thought of simply resampling my dataset. For example, suppose a subject is 15 years old with 3 events and has missing data for the dates. Then I would simply sample an outcome vector among other subjects of 15 years old, with 3 events and known outcomes.

That shouldn't introduce a biais no?